# List comprehension with lambda

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

How can I rewrite this loop using lambda and list-comprehension?

```
n = 17
e = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    e += 1 / factorial(i)
print(e)
```

So far I have tried this...but it's not working

```
lst = [item for item in map(lambda e: e + 1/factorial(i), range(0,n))])

myMap = map(lambda e: e + 1/factorial(i), range(0,n))
```

Comment: `e = sum(1 / factorial(i) for i in range(n))`

Comment: Why?  For readability, (Pythonic-ness); it should probably remain as a loop.  (Would help to have more context on the use case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since list comprehension and lambda do not fit well *in this case*, here some **functional programming** base approaches to, hope, make clear the difference (between a comprehension expression):

A [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) approach: a list is contracted to a "number" via a functional

```
from math import factorial
from functools import reduce

n = 10
reduce(lambda i, j: i + 1/factorial(j), range(n), 0)
#2.7182815255731922
```

here with `map`: consecutive 1-to-1 correspondences in which a function is applied termwise. Finally, the `sum` functional contracts the list into a "number".

Note: it should be read from right to left, apply the factorial, then the reciprocal and sum it.

```
sum(map(int(-1).__rpow__, map(factorial, range(n))))
#2.7182815255731922
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the sum function for this. I also don't understand why you are using the map function together with a list comprehension.

```py
e = sum([1 / factorial(i) for i in range(n)])
```

As you can see, list comprehensions can also be used to modify the returned list. You don't need to do complex and not working things using map and lambda.

To be complete, the map function returns the sum of all values in a list. For example:

```py
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
>>> sum(l)
21
```

When your n value gets larger and you need to start paying attention at efficiency, you can use the following code:

```py
sum(1 / factorial(i) for i in range(n))
```

I removed the square brackets here. This means that python creates a generator instance instaed of a list instance. A generator does not have all its values precalculated, instead it calculates them only when they are needed. This is way more efficient then a list, which first calculates all the values and then iterates over them.

Comment: There is not a need to build the extra list and append in every iteration. Efficiency can be gained by simply placing the iteration directly inside the `sum` function.  (In other words, drop the square brackets.)

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: A measure of efficiency can be gained by removing the square brackets from the `sum([…])` statement.  For example: `sum(1 / factorial(i) for i in range(n))`.  Now, an unneeded `list` is not being created and appended in every iteration.  Rather, a generator expression is created which *yields* each value in turn. (Granted, negligible with this small set, but noticeable with larger datasets.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I had an exercise where I was supposed to convert this code in a while loop, then represent the same result with lambda using map and list and list comprehension. Hence my question